# Sequentially execute webhooks received in node application

Tags: node.js, multithreading, design-patterns, producer-consumer, task-queue

I have a node application using koa. It receiving webhooks from external application on specific resources.

To illustrate let say the webhook send me with POST request an object of this type :

```
{
  'resource_id':'<SomeID>',
  'resource_origin':'<SomeResourceOrigin>',
  'value' : '<SomeValue>'
}
```

I would like to execute sequentially any resources coming from the same origin to avoid desynchronization of resources related to my execution.

I was thinking to use database as lock and use cron to sequentially executing my process for each resources of same origin.

But I'm not sure it's the most efficient method.

So my question is here :

Do you know some method/package/service allowing me to use global queues that I could implement for each origin insuring resources from same origin will be executed synchronously without making all webhooks processed sequentially ? If it do not use database it's better.

Comment: You can do it in-memory if you don't mind the footprint and the queue being dropped on process end.

Comment: "method/package/service allowing me to use global queues" - [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)?

Comment: I was thinking about RabbitMQ but I wondering if it's not a too heavy solution for the few use cases  I have.

Comment: Depends. What's your use-case? How scalable?

Comment: Accurately I receive some webhooks from differents online shop and I want to insure that there is no parallel resources management on the same shop. Let say at the moment there is 100 shop with 10 to 200 request by day.

Comment: How important is it to remember webhooks that were received but not yet processed?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent parallel resources management?

Comment: To answer first point  it's important because webhook send me the resource to manage in the shop and the change made in the shop.
Second point because I'm working with product inventory so parallel execution on the same resources lead to issue.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: So you need to persist the webhook before processing to a database of some form anyway, whether your own or RabbitMQ.

Comment: IMHO RabbitMQ will be the easiest solution here.

Comment: I'm implementing it . But to me it's the right answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution I decide to use

### Small brief of the post discussion

As ***Ivan Rubinson*** let me know my problem is just a [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

So I finally chose to use [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com) because I have a huge amount of webhook to process. For peoples having a small amount of request to process and do not want use external tools [O. Jones answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823946/5286953) is a real good way to solve the problem.

### Solution design

I finally install and configure a RabbitMQ server, then I created for each origin of my web-hooks one queue.

#### Producer

On the producer side when I receive the web-hook data I send a message to the queue corresponding to the origin of my web-hook with serialized information needed to process in fact id of the row in the Database to make messages as light as possible.

#### Consumer

On the consumer side I create a consumer function for each origin queue and set the fetch policy to one to process message one by one in each queue finally I set the channel policy to wait an acknowledgement message before to send the next message . Wit this configuration consumers proceed message by message and solve the initial problem.

### Implementation

#### Producer

```
   async function create(){
        await   amqp.connect(RBMQ_CONNECTION_STRING).then(async (conn)=>{
            await conn.createChannel().then(async (ch)=>{
                global.channel_publisher=ch;
            });
        });
    }

    async function sendtask(queue,task){
        if(!global.channel_publisher){
            await create();
        }
        global.channel_publisher.assertQueue(queue).then((ok)=>{
            global.channel_publisher.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(task));
        });
    }
```

I use the `sendtask(queue,task)` function at the place I received my web-hook

### Consumer

```
   async function create(){
      await amqp.connect(RBMQ_CONNECTION_STRING).then(async (conn)=>{
         await conn.createChannel().then(async (ch)=>{
            ch.prefetch(1);
            global.channel_consumer=ch;
          });
       });
    }

   async function consumeTask(queue){
       if(!global.channel_consumer){
           await create();
       }

       global.channel_consumer.assertQueue(queue).then((ok)=>{
          global.channel_consumer.consume(queue,(message)=>{
               const args=message.content.toString().split(';');

                    await processWebhooks(args);
                    global.channel_consumer.ack(message);
           });
       });
   }
```

I use the `consumeTask(queue)` when I had to process a new origin of web-hooks. Also I use it for initialize my application with all known origins in the database.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would start by serializing the handling of all your webhooks. In other words, I suggest you handle them one at a time no matter their origin. Use a simple queue inside your nodejs application.

(Once you've convinced yourself that works correctly, you can then serialize them based on origin.)

First, structure your function (let's call it `handleOneWebhook()`) for handling incoming webhooks as a Promise or an async function. Then you could invoke them using code with this outline.

```
let busy= false
async function handleManyWebhooks (queue) {
    if (busy) return
    busy = true
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        const item = queue.shift() 
        await handleOneWebhook (item)
    }
    busy  = false
}
```

The `queue` you pass to `handleManyWebhooks` is a simple array, where each element is the object from a POST request. You use it as a queue: `push()` each object to put it into the queue, and `shift()` to remove it.

Then, whenever you receive a webhook POST object you use code with this outline.

```
const queue = []
...

function handlePostObject (postObject) {
   queue.push(postObject)
   handleManyWebooks (queue)
}
```

Even though you call handleManyWebhooks once for each incoming object, the  `busy` flag makes sure it handles only one at a time.

Notice this is a very simple solution. Once you have it working correctly, two possible refinements suggest themselves.

1. Use something more efficient for your queue than a simple array. `shift()` is not very fast.
2. Create a separate queue object with its own `busy` flag for each separate origin. Then you will be able to parallelize the handling of webhooks from different origins while still serializing the stream of webhooks from each origin.

Comment: You solution fit exactly what I expected but it's my blame I didn't said I'm managing a  n important volume of request. So I finally choose to go on a rabbitMQ implementation with multiple queues.

Comment: Understood. RabbitMQ is an excellent way to handle a large volume of vital transactions like the  ones you mention.